# Why is the data returning nil?

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I am trying to access the data within an object, but I am getting a nil when I print it. Why is that happening and how do I fix it?

[image]

```
 print("card \(success!["data"]!!["brand"])")
```

Comment: The contents of `data` is an array. `()` -> Array – `{}` -> Dictionary

Comment: Even when I do `print("card \(success!["data"]!![8])")` it prints nil

Comment: @vadian am I doing it correctly?

Comment: No, try `if let data = success!["data"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] { print(data[0]["brand"]!) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
guard let success = result as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }
let data = success["data"] as! [AnyObject]
let firstObject = data.first! as! [String: AnyObject]
print(firstObject["brand"] as! String)
```

Comment: What if there is more than one card? I would need to change the `data.first`, but to what?

Comment: then it would be data[indexNumber], where indexNumber would be an integer.